# Load a frame/iframe through spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, iframe

I have a problem where when a user presses a submit button on the top of the page, another jsp is loaded in the frame/iframe below. I'm using the Spring MVC architecture and the jsp is decided by the controller. How should I make the controller map the jsp to the iframe? For all previous mappings I used @RequestMapping annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using Javascript, for example with JQuery you can do an ajax call when the `onSubmit` even is called on your form to load the response (html content) in your iframe:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : jQuery(this).serialize(),
        url : '/post_action',
        success : function(data, textStatus) {
            jQuery('#iframeId').contents().find('body').append('data');
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this thing --
$("#iFrameId").attr("src", "controller.mth");

this way the jsp returned from controller will be loaded in the iframe.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Ajax, Jquery. Can you tell me how to use this, where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring MVC, the ajax url worked after I used `request.getContextPath` in scriptlet.

My controller receives the request after this change and returns the jsp page. The jsp then display in an iframe after changing the `append('data')` to `append(data)` in example. Notice, **removed quotes** in data to make it work.

```
function openPage() {
  jQuery.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     data : jQuery(this).serialize(),
     url : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/post_action',
     success : function(data, textStatus) {
     jQuery('#iframeId').contents().find('body').append(data);
     },
     error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     }
  });
}
```